# Query to find tables being busy at the moment in Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

Please, suggest query to find tables (or, as an additional extra option(s), may be other objects in DB) **being busy at the moment of query** in Postgresql database, i.e.:

- table(s) is being filled at the moment of query
- table(s) is being read at the moment of query
- etc.

of course, query activity itself should be excluded from result as it is service/tool/maintanance activity.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT l.relation::regclass AS tablename,
       CASE l.mode
          WHEN 'AccessShareLock' THEN 'select'
          WHEN 'AccessExclusiveLock' THEN 'altered'
          ELSE 'modified'
       END AS activity
FROM pg_locks AS l
   JOIN pg_database AS d
      ON l.database = d.oid
WHERE d.datname = current_database()
  AND l.relation IS NOT NULL
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Comment: Thank you! Hope, this query won't take too much computing resources or disrupt basic activity or overload RDBMS to find out activity while being used in cycle/loop pretty frequently.